# expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token

Tags: c

I was making a program on doubly linked lists but I kept getting the following errors:

```
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before = token 
expected , or ; before = token      
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before -> token 
expected , or ; before -> token
```

The following is the part which shows the error:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
typedef struct node{
        int data;
        struct node *next,*prev;
        }n;
n *head,*a;
head=(n *)malloc(sizeof(n));
head->next=head->prev=NULL;
```

I tried a lot of things before coming here. A little help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Code **must** be inside functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `head=(n *)malloc(sizeof(n));` and `head->next=head->prev=NULL;` inside of `main()` or another relevant function. You can't have arbitrary statements in the toplevel.

Comment: Also, make sure that your compiler isn't trying to compile your C code as C++ code.